Issue with tests generating (magento. mftf)
mftf is new experience for me and sry if this question is to lamer
When i execute the following command
vendor/bin/mftf generate:tests
the following result is appears:
Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/Config/Dom.php on line 272

Warning: Attempt to read property "length" on false in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/Config/Dom.php on line 274

Warning: Attempt to read property "length" on false in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/Config/Dom.php on line 276

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function appendChild() on null in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/Config/Dom.php:134

Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/Config/MftfDom.php(60): Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Config\Dom->mergeNode(Object(DOMElement), '')
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/Config/Reader/MftfFilesystem.php(42): Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Config\MftfDom->merge('<test name="Add...', '/var/www/html/v...', Object(Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Exceptions\Collector\ExceptionCollector))
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(134): Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Config\Reader\MftfFilesystem->readFiles(Object(Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Util\Iterator\File))
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/Config/Data.php(100): Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->read('Test')
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/Config/Data.php(36): Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Config\Data->load()
#5 [internal function]: Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Config\Data->__construct(Object(Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Config\Reader\MftfFilesystem))
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/ObjectManager/Factory.php(251): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\ObjectManager\Factory->create('Magento\\Functio...')
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/ObjectManager/Factory.php(160): Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Functio...')
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/ObjectManager/Factory.php(242): Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\ObjectManager\Factory->resolveArguments('Magento\\Functio...', Array, Array)
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(58): Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\ObjectManager\Factory->create('Magento\\Functio...', Array)
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/Test/Handlers/TestObjectHandler.php(219): Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Functio...')
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/Test/Handlers/TestObjectHandler.php(65): Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Test\Handlers\TestObjectHandler->initTestData(true)
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/Suite/Util/SuiteObjectExtractor.php(193): Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Test\Handlers\TestObjectHandler::getInstance()
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/Suite/Util/SuiteObjectExtractor.php(82): Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Suite\Util\SuiteObjectExtractor->validateSuiteName(Array)
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/Suite/Handlers/SuiteObjectHandler.php(136): Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Suite\Util\SuiteObjectExtractor->parseSuiteDataIntoObjects(Array)
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/Suite/Handlers/SuiteObjectHandler.php(67): Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Suite\Handlers\SuiteObjectHandler->initSuiteData()
#17 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/Util/TestGenerator.php(242): Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Suite\Handlers\SuiteObjectHandler::getInstance()
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/Console/GenerateTestsCommand.php(215): Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Util\TestGenerator->createAllTestFiles(Object(Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Util\Manifest\DefaultTestManifest))
#19 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(326): Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Console\GenerateTestsCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1078): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#21 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(324): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Console\GenerateTestsCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#22 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(175): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#23 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/bin/mftf(40): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#24 /var/www/html/vendor/bin/mftf(119): include('/var/www/html/v...')
#25 {main}

  thrown in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/Config/Dom.php on line 134


i've try to rebuild project, clearing cash
I didn't have any problems with test generation before (they were in another, lol), but maybe after my some kind of intervention this problem did occur
